# Dynamically handling image resource

Tags: android, dynamic, bitmap

I want to change the image resource for bitmap dynamically. But I can't call them with name from the drawable class.

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.getImage(foldername + "/" + imagename));
```

I need to do something like that but I couldn't find the proper way of doing this.,

EDITED

I think I should be more clear. I store my images under the drawable folder and they are separeted into other folders.

For example;

drawable/imageset1, drawable/imageset2,

and I want to change the Image resource for bitmap depending on user input.

For example:
User selects imageset5 from first spinner, and selects image5.png from another spinner.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273828/dynamic-naming-of-resources-in-android-without-getidentifier/11273920#11273920

Comment: @Srht, I have prepared demo, which is working. It something like duplicate code, but if you want it, then just comment here.

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani It doesn't worked for me. Yes I would like to have the working code.

Comment: I works when you store images under drawable folder. But It does not work for folder hierarchy. I think Android does not support folders under drawable.

Comment: I have added and updated answer, just check it.

Comment: can't you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories in my answer which clearly says that you cannot access images from sub-folder created in your drawable folder so are you still doubtful?

Comment: @Sam.Janz I have seen it but it would be better if I could use folder hierarchies. So I'm trying to find a way around. Creating any folder under res folder is also forbidden?

Comment: you can try like category1image1 and then instead passing full name of image just pass the index of category and the image to get resource it would be a better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will do what you want

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getResources().getIdentifier(foldername + "/" + imagename , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

EDITED:

while the above code will work only if you follow android rule which doesn't allow sub directories in drawable folder so the above code will work only when directly accessing images from drawable.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getResources().getIdentifier( imagename , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

As these links describe

[How to access res/drawable/"folder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551810/how-to-access-res-drawable-folder)

[Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

Answer (score 0):

Make one array of image resources

```
int []a = int[]
{
   R.drawable.one,
   R.drawable.two,
   R.drawable.three,
   R.drawable.four,
};
```

Then access it in loop

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
   //  a[i]
}
```

Comment: I have more than 500 images separated into folders.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a resource stored in the drawables folder? Then try this method from BitmapFactory

```
public static Bitmap decodeResource (Resources res, int id)
```

Where

```
res = getResources()
```

and id is the id of the drawable like

```
R.drawable.picture
```

Check it out [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

you can't do like this. You have to add all images in drawable & use it like

`myImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageName)`

or after downloading the image from web you can apply as

```
myImage.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in));
```

to get the bitmap where in is `InputStream`

Answer (score 0):

Just try following:
Your image having name "imagename" must be in the folder

```
String IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME = "YOUR_IMAGE_CONTAINING_FOLDER";
```

Now, use following code:

```
String imagename = "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME";    
String PACKAGE_NAME=getApplicationContext().getPackageName();    
int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier(PACKAGE_NAME+":"+IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME+"/"+imagename , null, null);
System.out.println("IMG ID :: "+imgId);    //    check this in log
System.out.println("PACKAGE_NAME :: "+PACKAGE_NAME);    //    check this in log
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgId);
```

Comment: @Srht, If this code don't work and log displays error, then post that error here.

Comment: I created a folder under res named "teamimages" but it doesn't let me compile with that folder.

Comment: I couldn't even compile. It says your project contains errors. And shows the image folder in package explorer as a error.

Comment: I think android also doesn't let us to create folders as we wish.

Comment: Wait, i check by adding "teamimages" it in my project

Comment: `(int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier(MatchSelectionActivity.PACKAGE_NAME+":"+"teamimages"+"/"+Global.leagueId+"/"+Global.homeTeamId+"/logo", null, null);)`

Comment: No, android doesn't allow it. You can put your Images only into "drawable" OR in the "assets" folder. I also checked it.