# Getting image from image view and Upload to php-Server

Tags: java, android, image-uploading

I got this code that takes an **`image`** called **"dmlo"** from `drawable` and **upload it to php server**, all I want is **instead of taking that picture from drawable** I want to take it **from an `imageview`** , what should I do ? Should I replace any code in the first line by another one ?

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.dmlo);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new
    HttpPost("http://192.168.1.38/mobileappd/base.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4529235/1434631

Comment: @moonwalker Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it returns image in drawable format and after getting image from imageview you can pass object of Drawable to php server.

```
ImageView mImg1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImg1);
// For get Drawable from Image
Drawable d = mImg1.getDrawable();

// For Convert Drawable to Bitmap
Bitmap bitmapOrg = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it Dipak
I wrote :
Drawable d=photo.getDrawable();   // photo is an ImageView
It's giving an error in this line : 
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),d);
The function decodeResource is not taking it as an argument

Comment: @moonwalker write this Bitmap bitmapOrg = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap(); instead of Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.dmlo);

Answer (score 1):

Check this code - it might return null if no drawable is assigned

```
imageView.getDrawable();
```