# How to change the image button background upon clicking?

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have an image button as a on/off button, i want to change the source image of it upon clicking to switch between on and off, all i have to do is to place a comparison in my click listener and a switch operation, the switch goes fine, the problem here is with the comparison, i tried like million ways and all didn't work,

for example i tried:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == power) {

             Drawable fDraw = power.getBackground();
             Drawable sDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.acoffdormant);

             Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)fDraw).getBitmap();
             Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)sDraw).getBitmap();

            if (bitmap == bitmap2) {
                power.invalidateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.acoffdormant));
                power.setImageResource(R.drawable.acondormant);
            } else {
                power.invalidateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.acondormant));
                power.setImageResource(R.drawable.acoffdormant);
            }
        }

    }
};
```

And also:

```
if (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.acoffdormant).hashCode() == power.getBackground().hashCode())
```

And Also:

```
v.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.acoffdormant).getConstantState())
```

And Also :

```
                Drawable state = power.getBackground();
                Bitmap statebit = ((BitmapDrawable)state).getBitmap();
                Bitmap off = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(power.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.acoffdormant);

                if (statebit == off) {
                    power.invalidateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.acoffdormant));
                    power.setImageResource(R.drawable.acondormant);
                } else {
                    power.invalidateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.acondormant));
                    power.setImageResource(R.drawable.ac_fan);
                }
```

And Also:

```
        if (power.getBackground().getConstantState().equals
                (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.acoffdormant).getConstantState()))
```

And my **XML** :

```
    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:text="@string/power"
                            android:textColor="#00CCCC"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/power"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/acoffdormant" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526585/imageview-drawable-id-in-android

Comment: You don't need to mess around with Bitmaps. setImageResource() alone will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tag attribute` available for `imageButton`..

By default in your xml give the tag as **off**..

```
<ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/power"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/acoffdormant"
                            android:tag="off" />
```

**Then on button click:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {

String tag = power.getTag().toString().trim();

if(tag.equals("off"))
{
    power.setImageResource(R.drawable.acondormant);
    power.setTag("on");
}
else if(tag.equals("on"))
{
    power.setImageResource(R.drawable.acoffdormant);
    power.setTag("off");
}


    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use selector in order to change image button / button dynamically

Selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/existing_image" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_image" />
</selector>
```

Or you can to set visibilty to **GONE** / **VISIBLE** on click of a button

Answer (score 2):

Use one flag variable like this,

```
    boolean flag = false; 

    public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v == power) {

        if (boolean) {
            power.setImageResource(R.drawable.acondormant);
            boolean = false;
        } else {
            power.setImageResource(R.drawable.acoffdormant);
            boolean = true;
        }

   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

`power.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourResource)`

Also remove the background resource from xml

remove
`android:src="@drawable/acoffdormant"`

Instead Set

`power.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.acoffdormant)` //in oncreate

Comment: yea also i tried that before, at all it keeps the old pic and makes the new one under it

Comment: remove the background resource from xml , if you set so

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this.

```
B_cancelSearch.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);

    }
        break;
    }
    return false;
    }

});
```

And the other is by using a drawable selector as AndroidHacker mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29):

```
power.invalidate();
```

or

```
power.postInvalidate();
```

**after the `if-else` block just near the end of the method.**

Comment: it works just great in comparison but it changes the image without removing the original resource image, so it gives me a combined images