# How to check which current image resource is attached to ImageView in android xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

I want to check which image resource is attached to `ImageView` in xml, I am  able to check that which image resource is attached to image view but my requirement is to how to check that the `ImageView` has the same resource which I have set into xml or not, based on that I need to perform some actions.Code always executes else part. Following is my code,

```
  if (regProfile.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ivpic)) 
    {
      Toast.makeText(_con, "Image is ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
      // new RegisterAsyntaskNew().execute(); 
    } 
  else 
    {
     Toast.makeText(_con, "Image isn't ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     // new RegisterAsyntask().execute(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Hi please have a try with this as follows

```
if (regProfile.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ivpic).getConstantState()) 
{
  Toast.makeText(_con, "Image is ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  // new RegisterAsyntaskNew().execute(); 
} 
else 
{
 Toast.makeText(_con, "Image isn't ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
 // new RegisterAsyntask().execute(); 
}
```

please use `.getConstantState()` to compare

visit

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.ConstantState.html

**EDIT:**

```
.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource)
```

Is deprecated in API21, so I changed Jitesh Upadhyay's answer.

Here is the code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static boolean checkImageResource(Context ctx, ImageView imageView,
        int imageResource) {
    boolean result = false;

    if (ctx != null && imageView != null && imageView.getDrawable() != null) {
        ConstantState constantState;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            constantState = ctx.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(imageResource, ctx.getTheme())
                    .getConstantState();
        } else {
            constantState = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource)
                    .getConstantState();
        }

        if (imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == constantState) {
            result = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: hi, why this method alaways return false, even the image src image is same with imageResource params? ( R.mipmap.testImage)

Comment: You can use ResourcesCompat which eliminates the need of the Build Version Check since it's done by the getDrawable() function.

Answer (score 27):

You can do something like following,

Set a `tag` either through xml or dynamically as per your requirement.

Through xml,

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageview1" 
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:tag="bg"/>
```

Dynamically,

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
imageView.setTag("bg");
```

Use  `imageView.getTag()` to retrieve image information.

```
String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(imageView.getTag());
```

Edit:

if you are changing `ImageView` background frequently then,

```
imageView.setTag(R.drawable.drawablename);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawablename);
String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(imageView.getTag());
```

Now you can make your check.

```
if (backgroundImageName.equals("bg"))  // here "bg" is the tag that you set previously
    {
      Toast.makeText(_con, "Image is ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
      // new RegisterAsyntaskNew().execute(); 
    } 
  else 
    {
     Toast.makeText(_con, "Image isn't ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     // new RegisterAsyntask().execute(); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but when i will change image of imageview then else part should be executed, thats why i was trying to get which resource is attached to the imageview.

Answer (score 8):

Same solution in **kotlin**:

```
if (regProfile.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ivpic).constantState) 
   { 
       Toast.makeText(_con, "Image is ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
       // new RegisterAsyntaskNew().execute(); 
   } 
else 
   {
       Toast.makeText(_con, "Image isn't ivPic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
       // new RegisterAsyntask().execute(); 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I face same problem but i resolved in kotlin Android

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {

    when (v!!.getId()) {

        R.id.exo_fullscreen_button -> {
            if (exo_fullscreen_icon.drawable.constantState == resources.getDrawable( R.drawable.exo_controls_fullscreen_enter).constantState) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Correct Image ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(activity, "wrong image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you get `resources` from?

Answer (score 1):

u can do like this. first u need to set tag property of imageview like this

```
 android:tag="ic_grade_grey_24dp"

if (viewHolder.imgfav.getTag().equals("ic_grade_grey_24dp"))  // here "bg" is the tag that you set previously
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "ic_grade_black_24dp", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // new RegisterAsyntaskNew().execute();
                viewHolder.imgfav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_grade_black_24dp);
                viewHolder.imgfav.setTag("ic_grade_black_24dp");
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Second", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                viewHolder.imgfav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_grade_grey_24dp);
                viewHolder.imgfav.setTag("ic_grade_grey_24dp");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I already answered on the similar topic here: [Get the ID of a drawable in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49407083/5524413).
The approach is based on tagging a view with a specified resource id in the custom `LayoutInflater`. Whole process is automated by a simple library [TagView](https://github.com/shuhart/TagView).

As a result, you can compare two drawables just by their ids:

```
TagViewUtils.getTag(regProfile, ViewTag.IMAGEVIEW_SRC.id) == R.drawable.ivpic
```