# Check what image is displayed in an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, image, android-imageview

So I know you can set the images of a ImageView like the following (assuming bun_picture is an ImageView):

```java
bun_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.rawbun);
```

but is there any way to check what image an ImageView is currently displaying?
Something like (NOTE: .getImageResource doesn't exist, I'm just using it to get across what I want to do):

```java
if(bun_picture.getImageResource() == R.drawable.rawbun) == true){
do something}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but is there some equivalent I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check which current image resource is attached to ImageView in android xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357706/how-to-check-which-current-image-resource-is-attached-to-imageview-in-android-xm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have called `mutate()` on either of the drawables, you can check if two drawables represent the same image by comparing their `ConstantState` fields.

```
ConstantState mine = bun_picture.getConstantState();
ConstantState other = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.rawbun).getConstantState();

if (mine.equals(other)) {
    // they are the same
}
```