# Change two images on button click (Android)

Tags: android, image, onclick, buttonclick

So, I want to make a button which every time it gets pressed, it changes the image above the button. I have 2 images in total, so I don't use arrays. Let's say I have image1.png and image2.png. The default image is image1 and after I press the button it turns to image2. If I press it again it turns to image1.

```
package blablablabla;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myicon);
}


public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:{
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.initial);
        return;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I thought of making an if statment: if the image is image1, then change it to image2 and vice-versa.

The problem:  after I change to image2, I can't switch back. I know I didn't write the code for that because I made it wrrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i think this might do:

```
package blablablabla;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView image;
boolean flag = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myicon);
}


public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:{
    if(flag)
    {       
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.initial);
        flag=false;
    }
    else
    {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.secondary);
        flag=true;
    }
        return;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: hello...suppose im performing this one activity.user click to glow image... what if user goes from one activity to another and again coming back to activity one will the button remain as glow?

Comment: @Wini I would suggest you to try these things out, and also look into saving instance state.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in your `onCreate()` where you retrieve your `ImageView`, you first need to use `setTag()` so that you can identify what image is already in it. Once an image for `ImageView` is set, you cannot get the resource ID back for it. This is just a work around so, do this:

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setTag(R.drawable.image1);
```

Now, in your `onClick()` you can do as follows:

```
int tag = (int) image.getTag();
if( tag == R.drawable.image1 ){
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2));
    image.setTag(R.drawable.image2);
}else{
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1));
    image.setTag(R.drawable.image1);
}
```

Based On: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14474954/1894684

*You can also use setImageResource() in place of setImageDrawable(). The former does the image decoding on the UI thread, though*

Comment: Hmm, I understand. But why you use set.ImageDrawable? I mean, you could use setImageResource too, right?

Edit: Oh, now I see the bottom text! Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: hello...suppose im performing this one activity.user click to glow image... what if user goes from one activity to another and again coming back to activity one will the button remain as glow?