# how to save imageView to gallery by using it's Id instead of its name?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.im);

```
            bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

            ImagePath=MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    bitmap,
                    "mm",
                    "mm"
            );
            URI = Uri.parse(ImagePath);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: You want to save image in `ImageView` right? you can't save `ImageView` as it's class

Comment: Try using `.getId()` , for more check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526585/get-the-id-of-a-drawable-in-imageview    That might help