# I want to compare imageview tag with imageview backgroundresource?

Tags: android, background-image, android-imageview, android-image

How to compare imageview tag with other imageview backgroundresource in android

```
if (imageview1.getTag() == imageview2.getbackground()) {
    // do something
}
```

Can we do it like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526585/get-the-id-of-a-drawable-in-imageview

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely feasible. I mean, you can use a drawable as a tag in an `imageView`. Since `==` just checks if they are the same instance, this comparison should work.

However, it is terribly inefficient to use a `Drawable` as a tag.

Also, what is your problem? What are you trying to do? What is not working the way you want it to work?

I feel like your question needs to tell us more before it can be answered.