# Get bitmap from imageview in viewpager with glide

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm showing in imageview with glide. User can save image on button click.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageViewPreview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

when i use this code it save whole screen image(Image and black space).

```
    imageViewPreview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imageViewPreview.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    imageViewPreview.layout(0, 0,
            imageViewPreview.getMeasuredWidth(), imageViewPreview.getMeasuredHeight());
    imageViewPreview.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageViewPreview.getDrawingCache());
    imageViewPreview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

when is use this, sometime it work but image get cropped in half or image go to up like **"android:layout_alignParentTop="true"**.

Comment: what is your Question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `Bitmap` from DrawingCache. After Settting image in `ImageView` you can get it as below:

```
    imageViewPreview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imageViewPreview.buildDrawingCache(true);
    final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache());
    imageViewPreview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

If you need full size image then this is not right way i think .A better solution would be to get it From `Glide` as `Bitmap` . If full image was loaded already it will be quick (from cache) if not then it will load the full image from server or you can still use `Drawing cache` in case of No internet connection and glide failure.

```
Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
    .asBitmap()
    .load("imageUrl")
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
           // Use resource here    
           }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I want to show the image to user, if user like then he can save it.

Comment: how to get resource on button click

Comment: For that you can use a `Tag`. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526585/get-the-id-of-a-drawable-in-imageview.