# How to check that the icon is displayed in the input field in android test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

[image: image showing an input element with the text "vag@gmail.com", and an "x" in a circle on the right]

The application has a custom email input field, how can I check that it displays the drawable icons in android test (espresso)

xml:

```
<com.my.mobile.kit.input.InputGeneral
        android:id="@+id/login_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        app:kitEndIconDrawable="@drawable/kit_ic_cleanitem_24"
        app:kitEndIconMode="clear_text"
        app:kitEndIconTint="@color/baseDeepGreyOne"
        app:kitLabelText="@string/m_auth_login_email_hint"
        app:kitLabelVisibilityMode="manual"
        app:kitPlaceholderText="@string/m_auth_login_email_hint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Did you see my answer?!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `isDescendantOfA`

```kotlin
    onView(
        allOf(
            withId(R.id.kitEndIconDrawable),
            isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.login_email))
        )
   ).check(ViewAssertions.matches(/* check matches R.drawable.kit_ic_cleanitem_24 */))
```

Where `kitEndIconDrawable` is the id of the `ImageView` inside your custom view

Matching a drawable is a different topic, there are several approaches, you can use tags or some check the Bitmap, see these questions:

[Using Espresso to test drawable changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763425/using-espresso-to-test-drawable-changes)

[How to use espresso to test vector drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638025/how-to-use-espresso-to-test-vector-drawables)

Answer (score 0):

This is a **custom** **view** then you should define custom `ViewAction` for **perform** **click** on that icon.

**Something like this :**

```
object OnCloseItemClick : ViewAction {
    override fun getConstraints(): org.hamcrest.Matcher<View>? {
        return ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(InputGeneral::class.java)
    }

    override fun getDescription(): String {
        return "whatever"
    }

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View) {
        val customView: InputGeneral = view as InputGeneral
        customView.close_item_id.performClick()
    }
}
```

Now you can test this :

```
   onView(withId(R.id.login_email)).perform(OnCloseItemClick)
```