# How can I pass the ID of dragged view into setImageResource(resID:Int) via Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, drag-and-drop, android-imageview

I want to move a picture into another empty picture. While doing this dragged picture should be removed and the drop target should copy the data which dragged picture contains.

```
        val myOnDragListener = View.OnDragListener { v, event ->
        val draggedView = event.localState as ImageView 

        if(event.action == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP){
            (v as ImageView).setImageResource(draggedView.id)
            draggedView.setImageDrawable(null)
        }

        true
    }
```

I can copy the dragged datas into `draggedView` using `localState`. After that when drop event occurs it should change the drop target's image resource but it doesn't. This is where the program collapses.

`setImageResource` says it wants an Int parameter but as far as I can see it only accepts `setImageResource(R.drawable.name)` syntax.

How can I pass the ID of dragged view into `setImageResource(resID:Int)` ?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526585/get-the-id-of-a-drawable-in-imageview) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try first setting tag with resource id

```
val myImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.my_imageView);
myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable_name)          
myImageView.setTag(R.drawable.drawable_name);
```

then you can get the tag

```
 val myOnDragListener = View.OnDragListener { v, event ->
    val draggedView = event.localState as ImageView

    val tag=draggedView.tag as Int
    if(event.action == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP){
        (v as ImageView).setImageResource(tag)
        draggedView.setImageDrawable(null)
    }

    true
}
```